# ASP.NET Where bundling of jQuery is defined?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have ASP.NET web forms project where in the Site.Master I included several jQuery libraries. E.g. jQuery, jQuery-UI, jQuery.validate, and so on.  The Site.Master also has "built-in" (by Microsoft when the project was initially created) bundling. So when I use Development Tools and Network Capturing I see that after all my .js libraries are loaded, the libraries /Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js and /Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js are loaded again. This messes up some things in the project.  So I need to find out where in the Bundling the last two .js libraries are loaded; and comment them (if possible).  I don't know how to disable the entire bundling or I would do that. But now I need to - at least - "fix" these .js from being loaded twice.
Where should I look in the solution?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider instead moving your jquery into bundles.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch  My concern is that I don't understand in which order the bundle loads the jquery and if it is not done correctly I will be still dealing with the mess.  If you know where and how to specify the order of how the bundles load the jquery, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: You specify the order.. it doesn't just happen magically.  You tell it exactly where and in what order you want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET Web Forms, you can remove Scripts etc from your BundleConfig Class in the App_Start folder, which will look something like this:

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
              "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
    }
}
```

Just remove the references to the old versions of jQuery and jQuery UI - or alternatively remove your references to the new versions in your `Site.master` and add new bundles into this config file.

**Source:** http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx

Comment: Adaam. Thank you very much. I will follow the suggestion and the link.

Comment: @Hidalgo Quite alright. If you would accept my answer, then I would be very grateful. Just a note: you must first include jQuery and then jQuery UI in order for it to work properly. jQuery is a dependency of jQuery UI.